# Upload files directly to S3, but using arbitrary AWS credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, rubygems, paperclip, carrierwave

I'm looking for a Rails gem that lets users upload a file directly to S3.

There are many gems for this: s3_multipart, s3_direct_upload, carrier_wave_direct, paperclip.

Unfortunately every gem can only use 1 AWS credential that is set in a config file. My application lets users upload files to their own S3 buckets using their own AWS credentials. Of course I can't set all of my user's credentials in config.rb since new credentials are constantly being added.

Any ideas how I can use existing gems to upload files directly, but using any AWS credential and bucket I pass in?

Comment: You might want to check [fog](http://fog.io/storage/) for this just set the fog object in before filter and with user specific credentials and you would have what you need

Comment: If you arent using a multithread server I think it can be done in carrierwave as well